# Bancroft's method implementation

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, mathematics

**Background**

I've written an algorithm to solve the three-dimensional Time Difference of Arrival (TDoA) multi-lateration problem. That is, given the coordinates of `n` nodes, the velocity `v` of some signal, and the time of signal arrival at each node, we want to determine the coordinates of the signal source. In my case, the problem was further complicated by the fact that only four nodes are available.

I tried numerous approaches, and found the most success implementing [Bancroft's method](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Bancroft_Method#:%7E:text=The%20Bancroft%20method%20allows%20obtaining,knowledge%20for%20the%20receiver%20location.). With it, I'm able to obtain remarkable accuracy and precision, as well as excellent efficiency. I leave mathematical commentary to the linked page, however I'll try to step through my code as clearly as possible.

---

`def find():`

The `find()` method of the `Vertexer` class does the actual leg-work. When a `Vertexer` object is constructed, the coordinates of the nodes to be used are passed as a `NumPy` array to the constructor. That array looks like:

```
[[x_1, y_1, z_1],
 [x_2, y_2, z_2],
 [x_3, y_3, z_3],
 [x_4, y_4, z_4]]
```

The times of arrival are passed as a `NumPy` array to the `find()` method. That array looks like:

```
[[t_1],
 [t_2],
 [t_3],
 [t_4]]
```

The math (as per above) is performed, then we iterate through (typically two) possible solutions, and append each solution to a list, `solution`.

```
        # Iterate
        for Lambda in np.roots([ lorentzInner(oneA, oneA),
                                (lorentzInner(oneA, invA) - 1) * 2,
                                 lorentzInner(invA, invA),
                                ]):
            # Obtain solution
            X, Y, Z, T = M @ np.linalg.solve(A, Lambda * np.ones(4) + b)

            # Append solution as NumPy array to `solution`
            solution.append(np.array([X,Y,Z]))
```

The final solution is obtained by taking the `min` from `solution`, with the `key` being an error function which gives the sum of squared residuals (RSS error) of the time of arrival of the predicted point at each node, minus the given time of arrival.

---

`def __post_init__():`

In my application, it could be that times inputted are "invalid" (don't correspond to an actual localization, even though the code will try to find one). I compute the minimum possible time of arrival difference, and the maximum possible time of arrival difference.

The minimum possible time of arrival difference is given by a source at the centroid of the nodes. I calculate the centroid with `centroid = np.average(self.nodes, axis = 0)`. Then, I find the time of arrival at each node and take the minimum.

The maximum possible time of arrival difference is given by the two furthest nodes in the network. I find this using a simple `O(n^2)` brute-force "algorithm". As of now, the code doesn't do much with this, except print the bounds.

**Goals**

1. Readability/Brevity:
   Of utmost importance is the readability/brevity of my code. Please, feel free to offer criticism of even the most minor grievances with regards to readability.
2. Efficiency

**Code**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
from random import randrange
import math

M = np.diag([1, 1, 1, -1])

@dataclass
class Vertexer:

    nodes: np.ndarray

    # Defaults
    v = 299792

    def __post_init__(self):
        # Calculate valid input range
        max = 0
        min = 1E+10
        centroid = np.average(self.nodes, axis = 0)
        for n in self.nodes:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(n - centroid)
            if dist < min:
                min = dist

            for p in self.nodes:
                dist = np.linalg.norm(n - p)

                if dist > max:
                    max = dist

        max /= self.v
        min /= self.v

        print(min, max)

    def errFunc(self, point, times):
        # Return RSS error
        error = 0

        for n, t in zip(self.nodes, times):
            error += ((np.linalg.norm(n - point) / self.v) - t)**2

        return error

    def find(self, times):
        def lorentzInner(v, w):
            # Return Lorentzian Inner-Product
            return np.sum(v * (w @ M), axis = -1)

        A = np.append(self.nodes, times * self.v, axis = 1)

        b = 0.5 * lorentzInner(A, A)
        oneA = np.linalg.solve(A, np.ones(4))
        invA = np.linalg.solve(A, b)

        solution = []
        for Lambda in np.roots([ lorentzInner(oneA, oneA),
                                (lorentzInner(oneA, invA) - 1) * 2,
                                 lorentzInner(invA, invA),
                                ]):
            X, Y, Z, T = M @ np.linalg.solve(A, Lambda * np.ones(4) + b)
            solution.append(np.array([X,Y,Z]))
    
        return min(solution, key = lambda err: self.errFunc(err, times))
```

**Sample Input/Output**

This (quite crude) code, which you can append directly to the code above, will "simulate" a source/node network, print the actual source coordinates, and pass the times of arrival/node coordinates to the algorithm. We work with light signals, and in kilometers.

Note that I'm aware this bit could be done much better. I'm interested
only in improving the algorithm above, this code is just to demonstrate the
algorithm's efficacy.

```
# Simulate sources to test code
#

# Pick nodes to be at random locations
x_1 = randrange(10); y_1 = randrange(10); z_1 = randrange(10)
x_2 = randrange(10); y_2 = randrange(10); z_2 = randrange(10)
x_3 = randrange(10); y_3 = randrange(10); z_3 = randrange(10)
x_4 = randrange(10); y_4 = randrange(10); z_4 = randrange(10)

# Pick source to be at random location
x = randrange(1000); y = randrange(1000); z = randrange(1000)

# Set velocity
c = 299792 # km/ns

# Generate simulated source
t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c
t_4 = math.sqrt( (x - x_4)**2 + (y - y_4)**2 + (z - z_4)**2 ) / c

print('Actual:', x, y, z)

myVertexer = Vertexer(np.array([[x_1, y_1, z_1],[x_2, y_2, z_2],[x_3, y_3, z_3],[x_4, y_4, z_4]]))
print(myVertexer.find(np.array([[t_1], [t_2], [t_3], [t_4]])))
```

Comment: Have you looked at `numba`? It limits the numpy functions you can use (I don't know off the top of my head if the ones you use would work as-is or not) but it provides Just-in-time compilation to C code that can execute significantly faster than native python code. Also your `x_1...x_4` and `t_1...t_4` generation could be done in one line each if you vectorize it. I didn't look in depth but guessing your `for` loops could be be vectorised as well if you're applying the same function to each node

Comment: @Coupcoup Thanks for the suggestions! `numba` looks interesting, I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: As a heads up if numba works for you I wouldn't worry about vectorizing the inner for loops (still do the `x_n` though), numba runs basically as fast with for loops as with vectorized functions because it's converting everything to vectorized c code already

Comment: Your value for the speed of light is a billion times too fast. The unit for that value is km/sec.

Comment: Try using [`distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) in your `__post_init__`.

Answer (score 1):

### Dataclass types

`nodes` has a type but `v` doesn't - it should probably be `: int`.

### Vectorization

First of all, you should probably do dimension (shape) checking on `self.nodes`. You probably have assumptions about the shape of this array that we can't see.

Also, this:

```
    for n in self.nodes:
        dist = np.linalg.norm(n - centroid)
        if dist < min:
            min = dist

        for p in self.nodes:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(n - p)

            if dist > max:
                max = dist
```

really smells as if it can be further vectorized. Reading the [documentation for norm](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html), it does accept an `axis`, so at the very least you should be able to make a `dist` array in one step without the need to put it in a loop. `min` can similarly be applied over a specific axis on an entire `ndarray`.

You should be able to eliminate the inner loop using broadcasting. However, I can't be more specific than that as I don't know the shape of `self.nodes`.

### Forced output

Don't do this -

```
    print(min, max)
```

in your post-constructor. It's not useful for headless or unsupervised execution. Instead, move all of your `min`/`max` code to a method that calculates and returns these values, so that the caller can decide what to do with them. Among other reasons, this will make unit testing nicer.

### Names

`errFunc` should be `err_func` by PEP8; `lorentz_inner` and so on.

### Tests

You're so close to having a useful unit test. The only thing missing is `assert`. For this to work, you may have to give up calling `randrange` and instead choose known, easily-verifiable values.